# Converting macros to templates

Tags: c++, templates, macros

Is it possible to convert any macro to a template?
In our company we have a large code base full of macros and we were wondering if such transformation is possible.

Comment: Depends. For some it may be possible, for others not.

Comment: @downvoters what is wrong with this question?

Comment: No you can't convert **any** macro to a template.

Comment: @Thereisnothingwecando: your question should at least show some examples (with code) of your macros. Otherwise it is off-topic here and too broad.

Comment: I am not at all joking. Macro are textual things: `#define BEGIN {` is possible (and *cannot* be given by some template) but unlikely. However, people often use macros in more organized & syntactic (or even semantical) way. So you *need* to give examples to get a meaningful answer, because the general answer is *no* ; however, for macros from your company (if you **show them!**) the answer might *often* be *yes* (or *maybe*). Hence I voted to close your question...

Answer (score 3):

For some macros you can, and you should. For instance things such as

```
#define MAX(a, b)  ((a) > (b) ? (a) : (b))
```

This is a bad macro for all the standard reasons: chiefly, it's not type safe and it evaluates its arguments more than once. You can replace it with this template:

```
template <typename T>
T max(T a, T b) { return a > b ? a : b; }
```

This doesn't have the former macro's drawbacks.

However, some macros cannot easily (or at all) be transformed; not only obvious things such has

```
#define MAX_SIZE  100000
```

but also macros that use some special behavior of the preprocessor, such as

```
#define STRINGIFY(c)  #c
#define MY_THROW      throw MyException(__FILE__, __LINE__)
```

Comment: #define MAX_SIZE can be done as a templated class on int where the member is const and value is 100000, as for STRINGIFY or MY_THROW I'm pretty certain that those could be changed to templates